# How to get around "source code string cannot contain null bytes" when eval is run without removing the null bytes

Tags: python, arrays, string, eval

I have a program where I encrypt `class.__dict__` and save it to a file in an array so the file looks something like this -

```
{'some name':[1, 2, 3], 
 'data':'''9ÈX§Ë¡¡Ö© îo[ y^5Ð¥"¢§«!fa¥mc^W''' #somthing like this but a lot longer
}
```

I then read it and need to decrypt data but before that, I need to get the data from the array that is currently a string which I did with `eval(fileContent)` and it gives me the error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/stemb/Documents/programing/python/programs/img editor/__init__.py", line 127, in 
<module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/stemb/Documents/programing/python/programs/img editor/__init__.py", line 102, in main
    save_code.auto_save_load()
  File "C:\Users\stemb\Documents\programing\python\programs\img editor\save_code.py", line 153, in 
auto_save_load
    data = eval(fileContent)
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

My reading function is this
     `data = open("./save." + GLOBAL.fileType, "r", encoding="utf-8").read()`

`json.loads` gives `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`

My code is -

```
    # imports
import json
import random
import time

print("Finished save_progress imports")


def encrypt(obj, log=0): #encrypt
    # set data
    data = str(obj.__dict__)
    key = "codeAsciEightAndMabyA_Seven" + str(time.time())  # crate key
    key = list(key)
    random.shuffle(key)  # randomize key
    cryptionKeys = list()
    encrypted = list()
    iMinus = 0

    for i in range(len(data)):  # create a random + or - for extra security
        cryptionKeys.append(random.choice(("+", "-")))

    # encode part
    for i, c in enumerate(data):
        # set individual data
        charAsci = ord(c)
        cryptionKey = cryptionKeys[i]

        done = 0
        while done == 0:
            try:
                charKey = ord(key[i - iMinus])
                done = 1

            except IndexError:
                iMinus += len(key)

        if cryptionKey == "+":
            encryptedOrd = charAsci + charKey

        else:
            encryptedOrd = charAsci - charKey

            if encryptedOrd < 0:
                encryptedOrd += 110000

                cryptionKeys[i] = "="
                cryptionKey = cryptionKeys[i]

        encryptedChar = chr(encryptedOrd)
        encrypted.append(encryptedChar)

        if log == 1:
            print("charNumb \/")
            print(i)
            print("charAsci \/")
            print(charAsci)
            print("cryptionKey \/")
            print(cryptionKey)
            print("charKey \/")
            print(charKey)
            print("encryptedOrd \/")
            print(encryptedOrd)
            print("encryptedChar \/")
            print(encryptedChar)

            print()

    encrypted2 = encrypted
    encrypted = ""

    for c in encrypted2:
        encrypted += c

    return str(encrypted), str(key), str(cryptionKeys)





def auto_save(GLOBAL): # the save func
    file = open("./save." + GLOBAL.fileType, "w", encoding="utf-8")
    encryptedGLOBAL, key, cryptionKeys = encrypt(GLOBAL)

    out = ("{'key':" + str(key) + ", 'cryptionKeys':" + str(cryptionKeys) + ", 'data':'''" + str(
        encryptedGLOBAL) + "'''}")

    print(out)
    file.write(out)

    file.close()


def auto_save_load(aclass): # the loading dunc
    data = open("./save." + GLOBAL.fileType, "r", encoding="utf-8").read()

    data = eval(data)

    key = data["key"]
    cryptionKeys = data["cryptionKeys"]
    encryptedGLOBAL = data["data"]

    print(key)
    print()
    print(cryptionKeys)
    print()
    print(encryptedGLOBAL)
```

Other answers have said to remove the null bytes but the encryption method needs them.
Please help.

Comment: Why use eval?  Couldn't you use the JSON module to read it in?

Comment: why do you call eval()?

I think you don't have to.

Can you show us the save() and the load() code (you can keep out the encrypt and decrypt function if you want).

By the way. did you look at the pickle module. you could just pickl;e the dict encrypt it and write to a file. and for loading you load, decrypt and unpickle.

Comment: Show code to fix. Create a [mcve]. The solution will involve JSON and base64 encode/decode if the data.

Comment: @gelonida I have tried pickle but it would only save the class as it started as and not all the changes to variables

Comment: Shouldn't be like that. Pickle should pickle the entire object with it's state at the time of pickling. but we have to see code for either the pickle or the non pickle solution